# Firebase: Security questions

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I like to secure my firebase database.

Is it the case that every firebase admin can see all the information in the whole database?

I dont want to see all these things. I want them to be kept hidden.

Comment: When you say admin, do you mean someone who has access to the Firebase project itself? Or do you mean someone who has some sort of admin version of your app?

Comment: i mean the project itself

Comment: Got it. At this time, you can only grant read access to all the information in the database or none of it. You cannot limit an admin's view of the console to some information in the database.